# Laravel schedule fire only once on initialization

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

When i use php artisan `schedule:run` command the `shuffleQuoteOfTheDay` method is evaluated once and then it does not fire it every minute.

**Kernel@schedule method**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

  $schedule->call('App\Services\MotivationalQuoteService@shuffleQuoteOfTheDay')->everyMinute();

}
```

**MotivationalQuoteService@shuffleQuoteOfTheDay method**

```
  public function shuffleQuoteOfTheDay(){

    $currentQuoteOfADay = $this->getQuoteOfTheDay();

    $randomQuote = MotivationalQuote::where('quote_of_the_day',false)->inRandomOrder()->first();

    $currentQuoteOfADay->update(['quote_of_the_day' => false]);

    $randomQuote->update(['quote_of_the_day' => true]);

    return $randomQuote;

  }
```

It does work once but not every minute, i have created jobs table.Can someone help me with this?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling):

**Here is the only Cron entry you need to add to your server:**

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. Then, Laravel evaluates your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Laravel's task scheduler does not stay in memory, it needs to be run every minute. It will then check which tasks need to be run in that minute and run them. When you run the task scheduler using PHP it just runs once, it needs cron to run it every minute.

**If your dev machine is a linux machine/homestead then you could test this lcoally.**

**To add a cron job:**

```
$ crontab -e
```

then add  `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` to the crontab file and save it.

Do not forget to start/reload cron service.

**On ubuntu:**

```
 $  sudo service cron reload
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will set it as accepted answer because you described with details what im supposed to do.

Comment: @JanCiołek Np mate. Happy coding!

Comment: Please add On Windows..

Answer (score 5):

You need to setup `cron` so it could run the `php artisan schedule:run` command every minute.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction):

> When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to your server, consider using a service such as Laravel Forge which can manage the Cron entries for you:
>
> `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
>
> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the  schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Comment: Thank you, it is working as it is supposed to work.I have thought it would fire up those functions based on database table.